# Color portion between two vertical lines on a graph in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, colors, plot

I have plotted a graph as below, plotted vertical lines at some specified X-axis points (which will be the results of my work), and I'm trying to color portion between two successive lines as shown in this graph.

[image]

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to reproduce this graph?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reproduce this graph, that is, color different parts of the plot differently, this can be done by setting the [LineSpec](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#inputarg_LineSpec) of the [`plot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command appropriately. For example:

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
% This plots a regular, one color graph
figure;
plot(x, y);
% This plots several parts of the graph differently, and sets a vertical line between them
xSeparator = pi;
leftside = x < xSeparator;
figure;
plot(x(leftside), y(leftside), 'b',...
    x(~leftside), y(~leftside), 'g',...
    [xSeparator xSeparator], [min(y) max(y)], 'r');
```

In the second `plot` command, we draw the part of `x` left of the separator in blue, the part right of the separator in green, and a vertical line at the separation in red. Look at the examples in the documentation for `plot` to see other possibilities of using it.